Unresolved referenceFirebaseMessagingService in Kotlin Multiplatform Android App
I’m working on a Kotlin Multiplatform (KMP) app and trying to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for push notifications in the Android part of my project. However, I’m encountering an issue with the following code:
package firebase.notification

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService


class AuctionFireBaseMessagingService: FirebaseMessagingService () {


}

Error
Unresolved reference: FirebaseMessagingService
I've already done the following:
Added Firebase to my project in the Firebase Console.
Placed the google-services.json file in the app directory.
Added Firebase dependencies in my build.gradle.kts.
Steps I've Tried:
Syncing the project with Gradle.
Cleaning and rebuilding the project.
Ensured the correct import is present: import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.
Despite this, I’m still getting the unresolved reference error. Am I missing something in the configuration? Any help would be appreciated!
Here’s my build.gradle.kts configuration for the Android module:

import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "2.0.0"
    alias(libs.plugins.google.gms.google.services)

}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        @OptIn(ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
        compilerOptions {
            jvmTarget.set(JvmTarget.JVM_11)
        }
    }
    
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach { iosTarget ->
        iosTarget.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "ComposeApp"
            isStatic = true
        }
    }
    
    sourceSets {
        
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.preview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)

            implementation(libs.koin.android)
            implementation(libs.koin.androidx.compose)

            implementation(libs.ktor.okhttp)



        }
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.runtime)
            implementation(compose.foundation)
            implementation(compose.material3)
            implementation(compose.ui)
            implementation(compose.components.resources)
            implementation(compose.components.uiToolingPreview)

            api(libs.koin.core)
            implementation(libs.koin.compose)
            implementation(libs.lifecycle.viewmodel)

            // latest compose navigation
            implementation(libs.navigation.compose)
            implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json)

            //resources share
            implementation(compose.components.resources)
            implementation(libs.ktor.core)
            implementation(libs.ktor.logging)
            implementation(libs.ktor.serialization)
            implementation(libs.ktor.negotiation)
            implementation(libs.ktor.sockets)





        }

        iosMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.ktor.darwin.ios)
                implementation(libs.ktor.ios)
            }

        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.mobile.auction"
    compileSdk = libs.versions.android.compileSdk.get().toInt()

    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    sourceSets["main"].res.srcDirs("src/androidMain/res")
    sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDirs("src/commonMain/resources")

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.mobile.auction"
        minSdk = libs.versions.android.minSdk.get().toInt()
        targetSdk = libs.versions.android.targetSdk.get().toInt()
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    dependencies {
        debugImplementation(compose.uiTooling)
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.annotation.jvm)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.protolite.well.known.types)
    implementation(libs.firebase.messaging)
    implementation(libs.firebase.messaging.ktx)
    implementation(platform(libs.firebase.bom))



}
compose.resources {
    publicResClass = true
    packageOfResClass = "auctionsystem_mobileapp.composeapp.generated.resources"
    generateResClass = always
}


Project level plugins
plugins {
    // this is necessary to avoid the plugins to be loaded multiple times
    // in each subproject's classloader
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.google.gms.google.services) apply false
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

